# Event listener in c# which listens to a TFS subscription

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, azure-devops

I would like to create a c# application which will trigger some code every time a build is finished in a TFS/VSTS server. I dont have much experince using event listeners in c# and subscriptions in TFS/VSTS but hopfully someone do.

I would appreciate all the help i can get, even just advices.

Comment: You can start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=vsts .

Comment: Thank you Styxxy i've acctually never seen that documentation before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the **[Subscriptions REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/hooks/subscriptions?view=vsts-rest-4.1)**, you can programmatically create a subscription that performs an action on an external (consumer) service when a specific event occurs in a team project. For example, you can create a subscription to notify your service when a build fails.

Supported events:

- build completed
- code pushed (for Git team projects)
- pull request create or updated (for Git team projects)
- code checked in (TFVC team projects)
- work item created, updated, deleted, restored or commented on
- message posted to a team room

You can configure filters on your subscriptions to control which events trigger an action.

[C# related samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/create-subscription?view=vsts#q-are-there-c-libraries-that-i-can-use-to-create-subscriptions) for your reference.

More details please take a look at official tutorial: [Create a service hooks subscription programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=vsts)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Patrick, this really helped.

Comment: How can I get a list of these events above that are available for me to subscribe to using the server side plugin interface for TFS2018?  I've been looking for hours for the official documentation for TFS2018 before it was renamed and it's nowhere to be found.  I know how to make a custom server side plugin but I can't see what events are available to subscribe to. I do not want a cloud solution.